# Magento 2 install new module commands

Tags: magento2

I am having problems installing my module in magento2 I copy my module to app/code and execute :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And then when I try to access my magento i get an empty page and nothing works after that:

But if I execute this commands as root everything works fine:

```
rm -rf pub/static/* var/* generated/*;
chmod 0777 var/ pub/ generated/;
chmod 0777 -R var/ generated/ pub/;
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I don't really understand all this commands and what they exactly do, I don't want to execute something I don't understand because it's too risky.

Can someone explain to me this commands, are they safe to execute and is there a safer and simple way to install a module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You only need to run `setup:upgrade` command**

**1. When you made changes in Setup script(InstallData, InstallSchema,

UpgradeData, UpgradeSchema, ...)**

**2. If you install Magento first time.**

**3. At the time of new module installation**

**4. After upgrade magento version.**

> **What will do `setup:upgrade` command**

**1)** Check module version in `setup_module` table

**2)** If version not available or new version added in module.xml, It will run setup script and add latest version number in table

If you made changes in **HTML, CSS, JS, ...** files you need to delete particular changed files from `pub/static` folder or run this command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> **Short Form:** php bin/magento s:s:d

If you made changes like **add new dependency in __construct() or changes in `di.xml`**, you need to delete changed files from `var/generation` folder or run this command

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> **Short Form:** php bin/magento s:d:c

If you made changes in **admin configuration, layout xml, ui component, phtml, ...** files you need to only clean or flush cache

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> **Short Form:** php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 1):

You only need following commands to install and run a module

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Actually this two commands are not sufficient either they give me the exception : The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: try these commands, they solved the 'generated' directory permission issue for me

`sudo adduser abc www-data`
`sudo adduser www-data abc`

Note "abc" is your system name

Answer (score 0):

https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/magento-2-useful-commands-list-391
search this everything is explained quite perfectly

Comment: Thanks but this link didn't really help for example explaining php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy by Static Content Deploy Using Command Line is not an explanation it's just telling you if you want to deploy static content do this ... I wanted to know what are the effects of this command on my magento and on others modules will it delete or modify something which might damage your magento if not done correctly same thing for other commands ...